# Google Calendar API: Event endTime is decremented by 1 day

Tags: java, datetime, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to use the Google Calendar API in my own Java class. Unfortunately, the endTime of the newly created event (vacation in this case) seems to decremented by 1 day.

Example: I create an event with startTime 2011-01-01 and endTime 2011-01-05 the event will show up in Google Calendar from 2011-01-01 to 2011-01-04.

This is what I got so far (just the date part, taken from the [Google Calendar API Developer's Guide](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html#CreatingSingle), changed to Date because I want All Day events):

```
...
CalendarEventEntry myEntry = new CalendarEventEntry();

DateTime startTime = DateTime.parseDate("2011-01-01");  
DateTime endTime = DateTime.parseDate("2011-01-05");

When eventTimes = new When();
eventTimes.setStartTime(startTime);
eventTimes.setEndTime(endTime);
myEntry.addTime(eventTimes);

Reminder reminder = new Reminder();
reminder.setMethod(Method.NONE);
myEntry.getReminder().add(reminder);

CalendarEventEntry insertedEntry = myService.insert(postUrl, myEntry);
...
```

Could this be somehow related to timezone issues? (I am from Germany)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you don't provide `DateTime.parseDate()` with a time it will default to midnight. An event starting at midnight on the 1st and ending midnight on the 5th will display in the interface as running as full-day events from the 1st to the 4th. The time period doesn't include any time *on* the 5th, so it won't be displayed as being on the 5th.

You either need to set the end time as 2011-01-05 23:59, or add a day to the end date.

Comment: Am I able to provide times while still keeping full-day events or is it best to increment the day before sending the event to Google? However, there is somthing like DateTime.setDateOnly(true)

Comment: @Markus An event running from 00:00-23:59 will be a full-day event.

Comment: But they are not really marked as full-day event. But as I have problems with adding a day to a specific date (e.g. using Calendar) I will use this time workaround.

Comment: @Markus It is displayed as a full-day event though. Use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) for datetime arithmetic to add 1 day.