# Google Calendar API Bug - End date is - 1

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

The Google Calendar API treats `end.date` as `end.date - 1`

My POST Payload

```
{
    'summary': 'THREE DAY EVENT',
    'status': 'confirmed',
    'start': {
        'date': '2020-01-27',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
    },
    'end': {
        'date': '2020-01-29',
        'timeZone': 'America/Los_Angeles'
    }
}
```

Which yields the following event on my calendar

[image]

Notice the end date of this 3 day all day even is minus 1

When I do a GET on the event id, I am returned a correct object.

```
{
    'kind': 'calendar#event',
    'etag': '"REDACTED"',
    'id': 'REDACTED',
    'status': 'confirmed',
    'htmlLink': 'REDACTED',
    'created': '2020-01-22T20:15:23.000Z',
    'updated': '2020-01-22T20:15:23.896Z',
    'summary': 'THREE DAY EVENT',
    'creator': {'email': 'REDACTED'},
    'organizer': {'email': 'REDACTED',
    'displayName': 'REDACTED',
    'self': True},
    'start': {'date': '2020-01-27'},
    'end': {'date': '2020-01-29'},
    'iCalUID': 'REDACTED',
    'sequence': 0,
    'reminders': {'useDefault': True}
}
```

I've seen this post -- [Google Calendar API: Event endTime is decremented by 1 day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4578550/google-calendar-api-event-endtime-is-decremented-by-1-day)

Per the Google Calendar API documentation: https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body

`end.date` -- `The date, in the format "yyyy-mm-dd", if this is an all-day event.`

For an `all-day` event, a time string is unneeded and the resulting event should be within the bounds I have provided. The resulting API response is correct, but the event in Google Calendar is not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the API [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body), the parameter `end` refers to the **exclusive** end time of the event, which contrasts with `start`, which refers to the **inclusive** start time.

That is, the end date is not included in the event, but the day before.

#### Reference:

- [Events.insert request body](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/insert#request-body)

I hope this is of any help.

Comment: I still don't see how this makes sense. A single day all-day event will have a start and end date that are equal. By this logic, wouldn't an event with equal start and end dates not exist?

Comment: @pyFiddler In any case, that's how the API is designed. The referenced source is quite clear on that. You can always create a Feature Request in [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:191627%2B) if you think this should be changed. But this is not a bug in any case. It's intended behaviour. Also, since your question was answered, please consider accepting this answer, as SO relies on this to share knowledge to other users.

Comment: While I don't agree this is how it should work. I will accept reality. Thank you for the explanation.